# how to add textfield as a custom view in leftBarButtonItems, here textfield need to be capable to typing

Tags: swift3, swift4

how to add a new view that view having textfield and buttons in it and how this view can be added in leftbarbuttonitmes, and textfield need to be capable to typing.

Right now I have added this view to leftbarbuttonitems successfully but my textfield is not capable to type. Is there any way by which we can type if we add in leftbarbuttonitems.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: Just paste below code in your viewDidLoad method.

```
        let viewLeftButton: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160.0, height: 32.0))

        let textField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: viewLeftButton.frame.size.height))
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        textField.placeholder = "Type here..."

        let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: textField.frame.size.width + 8, y: 0, width: 44.0, height: viewLeftButton.frame.size.height))
        button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

        viewLeftButton.addSubview(textField)
        viewLeftButton.addSubview(button)

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewLeftButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```